# Removing duplicate rows from one column without losing data from another column

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates, aggregate

I apologize if this has already been asked, but the solutions I came across didn't seem to work for me.

I have a data set that was initially multiple excel sheets containing different variables for the same subjects. I was able to import the data into r and combine into a single data frame using:

x1_data <- "/data.xlsx"

excel_sheets(path = x1_data)

tab_names <- excel_sheets(path = x1_data)

list_all <- lapply(tab_names, function(x)

read_excel(path = x1_data, sheet = x))

str(list_all)

df <- rbind.fill(list_all)

df <- as_tibble(df)

However, I now have many duplicate rows for each subject, as each sheet was essentially added beneath the preceding sheet. Something like this:

Sheet 1

- ID: 1,2
- Age: 32, 29
- Sex: M, F

Sheet 2

- ID: 1, 2
- Weight: 75, 89
- Height: 157, 146

Combined

- ID: 1, 2, 1, 2
- Age: 32, 29, NA, NA
- Sex: M, F, NA, NA
- Weight: NA, NA, 75, 89
- Height: NA, NA, 157, 146

I can't seem to figure out how to delete the duplicate ID rows without losing the data in the columns that belong to those rows. I tried aggregate and group_by without success. What I am after is this:

Combined

- ID: 1, 2
- Age: 32, 29
- Sex: M, F
- Weight: 75, 89
- Height: 157, 146

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(ID = c(1, 2, 1, 2), 
             Age = c(32, 29, NA, NA), 
             Sex = c("M", "F", NA, NA), 
             Weight = c(NA, NA, 75, 89), 
             Height = c(NA, NA, 157, 146))

df1 <- df %>% filter(is.na(Age)) %>% select(ID, Weight, Height)
df2 <- df %>% filter(!is.na(Age)) %>% select(ID, Age, Sex)

df.merged <- df2 %>% left_join(df1, by = "ID")
```

For future questions, please provide a already formatted sample of your data which makes it much more easier to work with.